# Where to find Android's original resource images

Tags: android

Does anybody know, where I can find the original image-files (button backgrounds, menu icons, etc.) used by Android? I'd need something like the text input background for my own view, but would like it to match the existing style as exactly as possible. Also I need the correct padding etc. But besides checking out the whole Android source from Github I have no idea where to find those images.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to the folder where you installed the Android SDK. You find the resources in

```
platforms > android-* > data > res > drawable-*
```

Answer (score 5):

the ids of the default android resources are saved in the android R class:

```
getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.*);
```

Note that R is `android.R` here and not `your.packe.name.R`!

The original files are saved in the sdk:

under `platforms/android-8/data/res/drawable` e.g. you can find them

Comment: Yes Jonathan, I know that. But I'm looking for the actual png Files to look at and use as a base for my own custom resource images.

Answer (score -1):

I found it:
/home/quyen/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-mdpi