# Resize checkbox image in Android programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, resize

I want to resize the image of the CheckBox programmatically, but i want to use the original images of the phone. I just want to scale it.
I don't wand to supply own images, because i want to keep the phone's look, and i would still have to scale them.
I already tried to get the systems image resources using 
[Setting Android CheckBox to a different image... and then back to the original images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235237/setting-android-checkbox-to-a-different-image-and-then-back-to-the-original-i?rq=1)
but i still could not scale the drawable. (I tried drawable.setBounds()).
I'll probably also have this issue with radio buttons.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you tried to scale your CheckBox height and width?

Comment: checkbox.setWidth() and checkbox.setHeight() have no effect.
checkbox.getLayoutParams().height=16 has effect but clips the contents (image and text), as do android:layout_width="16dip"
android:layout_height="16dip" in the layout xml.

Comment: I did not get an solution, so here is my partial answer: Starting with Android 11 one can use setScaleX() and setScaleY() on a view.

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to set the layout parameters on the checkBox:

```
LayoutParams lp = findViewById(R.id.chk_id).getLayoutParams();
lp.width = width;
lp.height=height;
findViewById(R.id.chk_id).setLayoutParams(lp);
```

By getting the layoutparams before you presever any other layout setting associated with the view

width and height are in pixels, to scale it for density use:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = (int)(150*dm.density);
```

you need to use the Container class for the Layout params this example is for a FrameLayout but just replace that with tyhe type of the parent container.

Comment: this looks reasonable but i don't find `R.id.chk_id`. I tried `android.R.id.chk_id` but there is only `.checkbox` (which isn't the id of the checkbox image). 
If i misunderstood you here and `chk_id` stands for the id of my CheckButton, then the answer is: this does not work. It clips the contents (image and text) of the CheckBox.